# Powershell: Cast conditional statement to a variable

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if it was possible to save a conditional statement as a variable.

If I cast it to a variable with curved brackets () it will save the solution of the conditional statement.
If I cast it with quotes, it is obviously saved as a string.

What I'm trying to accomplish is having the if-statement calculate the conditional statement instead of it happening when casting to the variable.

For example:

```
$value = 0 
$statement = $value -eq 5
$value = 5  
if($statement) { Write-Output "value is 5" }
```

This should give me the output "value is 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$value = 0 
$statement = { $value -eq 5 }
$value = 5  
if(& $statement) { Write-Output "Test1: value is 5" }
$value = 2
if(& $statement) { Write-Output "Test2: value is 5" }
```

Output is:

```
Test1: value is 5
```

`$statement` is of type ScriptBlock, and the `&` operator will execute a script block when one is passed to it.

Comment: This seems to be it. Thank you for helping me as well as explaining how the solution works!